# Sending e-mail to all users with an account using ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am trying to send a daily e-mail to all registered users using ActionMailer.

The scheduling part is fine, I just can't figure out how to send the e-mail to each user... There is probably a simple solution, but it has been a very long day.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What's the exact problem? Why not just `User.all.each { |u| ... }` etc.?

Comment: I don't know where to put this code. In the scheduler? or the mailer model? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using for scheduling?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very straightforward:

```
scheduler.cron '0 0 22 * * *' do
  # every day at 22:00:00
  User.all.each do |user|
    # Send your email
  end
end
```

To be honest, if you couldn't think of this solution yourself, I think you should learn more about the basics of Rails before going any further.

That said, you should also keep in mind that if your user base becomes large, sending an email to each user every day can quickly become difficult (you may need to distribute the load to other servers) and sending mass emails to this extent will put your IPs and domains at risk of being flagged as spam. How to avoid this is not trivial and involves dozens of complex techniques (SPF, DKIM, correct rDNS records, whitelisting services, and so on.)

What I'm trying to say is that if you want to scale this to many users, you'll need to know a lot more than simply how to send out the emails.